# Is this the Facade pattern? If not then what?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out what this design pattern is. I used it often when I have common logic that needs to execute on/for a single object.

I am thinking maybe **Facade**?

E.g. `Validation`

A public interface

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    void Validate(T obj);
}
```

Multiple implementations

```
public class CodeValidator<T> : IValidator<T> { public void Validate(T obj) { } }
public class PerfValidator<T> : IValidator<T> { public void Validate(T obj) { } }
public class DotValidator<T> : IValidator<T> { public void Validate(T obj) { } }
public class NetfValidator<T> : IValidator<T> { public void Validate(T obj) { } }
```

And then a class takes either a `IValidatorCollection` or straight `IEnumerable<IValidator>` which injects all registered validators.

```
public class PostValidaitonController
{
    private IEnumerable<IValidator<Post>> _validators;

    public PostValidaitonController(IEnumerable<IValidator<Post>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public void Validate(Post post)
    {
        foreach (var validator in _validators)
        {
            validator.Validate(post);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I know this uses IoC/DI to inject the collection of `IValidator<T>` but that is not the pattern I am looking for. Its the pattern that you hide multiple implementations of an `interface` behind a single `interface`/`class`

Comment: Looks like a strategy to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: Indeed it does! Interesting, thought strategy was something completely different haha! Thanks!

Comment: I'd say the real pattern here is IoC... on a side note beware of that `IEnumerable<T>`, as you don't really know what multiple enumerations will do. I'd either use `ICollection<T>` instead, or write `_validators = validators.ToList()` to materialize the enumerable only once. Unless, of course, if you depend on this behavior.

Comment: This is is based on the Inversion of Control programming paradigm. I may be wrong but I thought façade was just another term for implementing a client wrapper of an external api, or a go between of two repositories.

Comment: It's not a facade pattern because it's not presenting a *new* interface that wraps the interface of two or more objects.  Strategy is close, but strategy generally abstracts a single policy not a collection of policies.  Other *close* possibilities might be Mediator and Iterator

Comment: I wouldn't call this IoC, as that generally entails a container responsible for resolution of the concrete types to be used via an abstract interface.  There's no information to resolve which types to use for the abstract interface (other than all the same type).  It certainly uses Dependency Injection Pattern...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it's probably less ideal to hold a List of validators as it would be unnesecary to create a new list to hold validators, when all i ever will be doing is enumerating over them. I will waste more memory + CPU cycles. All I need is an `enumerator` of all the validators, each and every time, I would only be iterating over them so its cheaper to hold a reference to an IEnumerable than it is to create a new List.

Comment: I know it uses IoC/DI ( but thats not the pattern I am trying to figure out the name of)

Comment: Chain of Responsibility seems like a close fit as well. But there is no "handled" where it should stop. It should always go through every single step.

Comment: Fwiw one would normally continue the pattern and make a class like `PostValidationController` implement `IValidator<T>` so that you can represent a collection of validators as just another validator.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've given is a good example of the **Strategy pattern**.

Both the implementers of the Validator strategy and the users of the Validator depend on the abstraction IValidator.

This keeps the Validation users from caring about the details of particular Validation operations.

This also keeps the Validation implementers from caring about how or when a given Validation is performed.

**Edit:** In fact, under the wiki entry for strategy pattern it explicitly mentions Validation:

> For instance, a class that performs validation on incoming data may
>   use a strategy pattern to select a validation algorithm based on the
>   type of data, the source of the data, user choice, or other
>   discriminating factors. These factors are not known for each case
>   until run-time, and may require radically different validation to be
>   performed. The validation strategies, encapsulated separately from the
>   validating object, may be used by other validating objects in
>   different areas of the system (or even different systems) without code
>   duplication.

Comment: Most things I read about Strategy seems to be "selecting" a single "strategy". It does definitely seem to be the best fit. But there is something quite not right

Comment: The single strategy of the IValidator is to validate a given object. That you are injecting a collection of strategies for the controller to use does not change that. The controller will simply execute each of the validation strategies that it is given. Use of strategy pattern is about selecting the right one, but nothing about selection is inherent in the strategy pattern. In this case, the strategies are selected by your DI container and injected into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The closest match imho is actually [bridge](http://www.dofactory.com/net/bridge-design-pattern) pattern, but not really. You're decoupling the validation rules/logic from the `Validate` method. While clients rely on the `Validate` method, you can actually modify the rules dynamically, based on some kind of criteria.

I've written such code before, albeit a little bit more complicated (eg the order of validation rules can be configured dynamically), I wouldn't personally classify it as any pattern. You're simple using dependency injection to decouple the validation rules from the actual validation process.

That said, I don't like the injection of list validations. You might want to consider refactoring it into strategy pattern (eg `ValidationStrategy`), and move the Validate method into there instead. Right now, most of your controllers get this "long" type, which is not that readable, plus, you'd have to duplicate the "Validate" method to each controller, or move it to base class (which I don't think is correct place).

Ps, to me your current solution does not look like strategy. Maybe "implementation wise", but the point is to get the intent right, as some of the patterns are implemented quite similarly anyways, but differ in their intent.